# How can I move mouse cursor and click?

Tags: windows, batch-file, mousemove, mouseclick-event

Like my question, how can I do it? I have started making a .bat file which will open websites and now I want it to move the cursor into a specific X'Y location of the screen and left click. Is there a way I can do it in .bat or in any other type of script?

Thanks in advance,
-Stam

Comment: I believe that isn't possible with the standard set of command available in a batch file. You can still use a batch file, but you'll probably need to use another scripting language. I myself have done this using the win32api module in Python. You can also check the possible duplicate I mentioned.

Comment: And if you can't install third party software because of work, PowerShell is installed on Windows natively and should also be able to do this.

Comment: If you're opening websites using the `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object, you could programmatically `DOMelement.click()`.

Comment: the best thing out there for web automation is [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) . It supports few languages - including C# that is installed by default on every windows machine

Comment: with `.bat` file? 0_o are you sure you chosen the right way of doing this? I'd recommend to go **NUnit** and **Selenium** to do browser automation/testing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the [**mouse.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/mouse.bat) - it is a self compiled C#/batch file and does not require external tools and the source is visible and editable.

Examples:

```
//clicks at the current position
call mouse click

//double clicks at the current position
call mouse doubleClick

//right clicks at the current position
call mouse rightClick

//returns the position of the cursor
call mouse position

//scrolls up the mouse wheel with 1500 units
call mouse scrollUp 150

//scrolls down with 100 postitions
call mouse scrollDown 100

 //relatively(from the current position) moves the mouse with 100 horizontal and 100 vertial postitions
call mouse moveBy 100x100

//absolute positioning
call mouse moveTo 100x100

//relative drag (lefclick and move)
call mouse dragBy 300x200

//absolute drag
call mouse dragTo 500x500
```